# Is it possible to set an Excel Pivot Table filter value to a cell reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to make a Pivot Table more dynamic in Excel by filtering not on checked values from a list (as is the default method) but to filter on a value contained in a cell reference. Is this possible and if so, how?

The pivot table supplies data to a model somewhere else in my workbook, so being able to update a value and have the pivot table automatically refresh would be ideal.

Comment: If possible, I would prefer non-VBA solutions, but if it is the only way then please feel free to share.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**YES it's very much possible that you can use a Cell Reference to Filter records while using the Pivot Table.**

let me discuss one simple example. Suppose you have database in **Range A2 to D20**. Contains Headers for example **Date, City, Name & Sales**. Now to work with Cell reference to filter, steps shown below should be followed.

1. Create a New Column `E`.
2. write a formula like `=and(D2<=1000,D2>=5000)`, press **E**nter.
3. Drag down the formula till end,(You find True & False as per Data).
4. While building the Pivot table, move New Field(Column) to `Report Filter` OR 
   to `Slicer` (if you have Excel 2010 or higher version).
5. Choose `True/False` from the Filter.
6. Go to Pivot-table Tools Options & hit **R**efresh.

You find Excel has included the New Field's effect and as per it shows the result.

**NB:** Remember in Place of TRUE you can use FALSE option also, you can use any possible method (Formula is better way) which can help Excel to Filter record.

**Hope this help you. In case my solution differs, just put a comment that where you need correction.**

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: I think this can work. You're proposing I create a formula for my table that produces a boolean value, and then filter on that value. So if I want to filter on an attribute "City" equal to "Toronto", I could point the formula to a reference cell somewhere where the user enters the city value. I'd then have to refresh my pivot table to see the adjusted values.

Comment: Nice to here from you, yes for the Formula you can use the Cell reference also from any where in the Work Book. Keep asking,,.

Comment: Since this works, I'll mark this as the answer. I think it's ideal in cases where conditions are simple, but if things are more complex (e.g. multiple filter values), it could get cumbersome. I think this is just a limitation of pivot tables, though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @macsmith, nice to hear from you again. If you need extremely complicated Data Filter, better use Power or MS-Query, or even Advance filter can  help you. If you feel I can suggest you how you can use it in better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2010 or later, then you can fake this without VBA because:

- a PivotTable with nothing but one field in the Filters pane looks and
  behaves pretty much exactly like a Data Validation dropdown does; and
- that PivotTable can be hooked up to the other PivotTables via
  slicers, so that it controls them.

I've written up exhaustive instructions at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/16/sync-pivots-from-dropdown/ and don't have time to reproduce them here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately my workplace uses 2007, so I can't test out this answer (I guess I should have specified the version in my question). I appreciate the help though! I'll try it out if we ever upgrade.

Comment: @jeffreyweir sadly this link is broken, possibly due to old age. If you get the chance to relink, I'm interested in your write up.