I would like to automatically filter a large dataset for reference elsewhere based on the filters selected in a PivotTable
I would like to take this dataset and put it into a pivot table where it will be sorted into the items I want to select. I then want that to update the table with the dataset so that I can reference the values in Column 4 that I'm sorting in another formula later on.
Is there a way to force the table to automatically filter to the the same filters that the Pivot Table has?
Database with Pivot Table Filters: Original Dataset and Pivot Table
What I want the database to filter to automatically:
Result
Edit: Somebody suggested using a logic check from the results of the filters and that works to an extent in a second pivot filter. All I really need is the X and Y (which the first filter table is filtered by) to be listed so I can reference it in a formula later. However, I can't narrow down anything in Column Four due to the cell returning "(Multiple Values)" when referenced instead of the values selected.
Current State

Here's a possibility: https://superuser.com/questions/1271447/is-it-possible-to-set-an-excel-pivot-table-filter-value-to-a-cell-reference

Hey this is great stuff! It's really close to what I need. The only issue is I still need to find a way to filter to the multiple values in Column Four. This only works for where a reference cell is selected. I was able to narrow down the results of a second pivot table to G,X,Y but I only want X and Y
